# Search Path for C Code Project

Tags: c

I have a third party Curl project, inside there is a lib folder containing the source file,
and also a include folder, inside include folder there is a curl folder which a bunch of .h files

```
 /lib/***.c   and /lib/***.h files

 /include/curl/curl.h
```

Inside the sources files of the /lib there are many calls to

```
 #include <curl/curl.h>
```

I copy the /lib and /curl folder into my new projects.  Now When I compiled there's an error on

```
  Lexical or preprocessor error on #include <curl/curl.h>
```

I added the Header search path and User search path

```
  "$(SRCROOT)/curl"
```

which points to /curl folder containing curl.h file.
but the project still has compile issue on

ANd I don't want to change that to just  because there are too many occurrences. ANy ideas?

Comment: What are you using to build this and what are "header search path" and "user search path"? Did you look at what command line the compiler ends up being invoked with to see if the paths come out right in the end?

Comment: header search path and user search path are entries in IDE to allow user specify the path.

Answer (score 0):

Use -I compilation flag to specify the include path.
e.g.

```
gcc -I/var/lib curl.c
```

If the #include is `#include <curl/curl.h>` then the header file will be found in directory  `/var/lib/curl`.

Comment: There will be a setting in whatever IDE you use which will determine compilation include search path.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`gcc curl.c -I/(PATH TO HEADER FILE)`

if you have any shared libraries to link then try this

`gcc curl.c -I/(PATH TO HEADER FILE) -L/(path to lib)`